# Load jQuery script after Ajax (filter) loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, filtering

I am currently running a couple of jQuery scripts on the same page, this particular page has a product filter on it (using ajax). http://www.ctagroup.com.au/cta-group-home/products/selector/

One script i am using is this:

```
var $s = jQuery.noConflict();
$s('body').each(function () {
$s(this).html($s(this).html().replace(/(\®)/g, '<sup>®</sup>'));
});
```

So each ® is used accordingly site wide.
When a filter option is clicked it then returns without my script being run.

How can i get this script to run again everytime the ajax filter is used?

Comment: Put it in a function and call it from the ajax filter code...

Comment: Note that since a document only has one body `$s('body').each(function () {
$s(this).html($s(this).html().replace(/(\®)/g, '<sup>®</sup>'));
});` is the same as `$s('body').html($s('body').html().replace(/(\®)/g, '<sup>®</sup>'));`, effectively replacing the entire body contents - could be pretty expensive to do that and break things.

Comment: FYI on your current page you are getting invalid regular expression flags (syntax error) in `var $s = jQuery.noConflict();
$s('body').each(function () {
$s(this).html($s(this).html().replace(/(\®)/g, '<sup>®</sup>'));
});`  Looks like this code MIGHT be in multiple places on your page and the global no conflict `$s` might be duplicated

Comment: compare the above to this also on the page with duplicate sup: `var $s = jQuery.noConflict();
$s('body').each(function () {
$s(this).html($s(this).html().replace(/(\<sup>®</sup>)/g, '<sup><sup>®</sup></sup>'));
});`  THIS is happening because of your global replace, it replaces itself and blows up - hence another reason I did the focused approach on the selector.

Comment: The reason there is a double <sup> is simply because i have <sup> around some text blocks throughout the site as this was before i figured out this function. Every other ® without a <sup> now has one. 
I replaced my bit of code with yours and all it did was target ® in the div class .sf-result. 
I think you're misunderstanding what i actually need. Every ® on the site now has a <sup> with my bit of code. When the filter is used you can see that in the product descriptions it changes back to normal. @Mark

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you NEED that `jQuery.noConflict();`, I cannot see why you would really; but here is an example without it.  NOTE I did NOT like the way you did it so, using your page I focused it a bit.  You can modify that as you see fit targeting specific elements with selectors.

Put in a custom event handler somewhere called **customFixReg**

```
jQuery(document).on('customFixReg', function() {
  jQuery('.sf-result').find('.prod-cont-selector').find('p')
    .filter(':contains("®")').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html()
           .replace(/(\®)/g, '<sup>®</sup>'));
  });
});
```

EDIT: Not liking the double selector this also works:

```
jQuery(document).on('customFixReg', function() {
  jQuery('.sf-result').find('.prod-cont-selector').find('p')
      .filter(':contains("®")').html(function(i, val) {
          return val.replace(/(\®)/g, '<sup>®</sup>');
      });
});
```

**Then, when; where you need it, trigger it:**

```
jQuery(document).trigger('customFixReg');
```

I grabbed some content and tested it here: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/j787Ljzz/

**Reference to comment**, your page has THIS in consecutive lines on the page: SO it breaks based on the prior code.  Line 789 on the page:

```
 <script>
var $s = jQuery.noConflict();
$s('body').each(function () {
$s(this).html($s(this).html().replace(/(\®)/g, '<sup>®</sup>'));
});
</script>

<script>
jQuery(document).on('customFixReg', function() {
  jQuery('ul.sf-result').find('.prod-cont-selector').find('h3,p')
    .filter(':contains("®")').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html()
           .replace(/(\®)/g, '<sup>®</sup>'));
  });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT: I found a bug if the trigger recurred, it would double wrap so I filter those with a child `<sup>` element out.**

```
jQuery(document).on('customFixReg', function() {
  jQuery('.sf-result').find('.prod-cont-selector').find('p,h3').filter(':contains("®")')
    .filter(function() {
      return !$(this).children('sup').length;
    })
    .each(function() {
      jQuery(this).html(function(i, val) {
        return val.replace(/(\®)/g, '<sup>®</sup>');
      });
    });
});
```

Updated sample: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/j787Ljzz/4/

Comment: The reason i needed `jQuery.noConfilct` is because i had other scripts which were breaking others.
Anyhow, I tried using the event handler which works until the filter is used. Once the filter is used it does not work.

Comment: The event handler has to be in code that is not replaced OR it should get re-inserted when that occurs like on a page refresh.

Comment: I can ONLY assume the `.trigger` is in some code in a linked library file right?

Comment: The `.trigger` is directly beneath the event handler

Comment: I am sorry, I do not see `jQuery(document).trigger('customFixReg');` on the page (view source on page) anywhere. That code should be placed in your product filter function (after it filters and the results are on the page), that code might be in one of your .js files but I have no knowledge of that.

Comment: Oh ok, i see now. Well the product filter is a plugin, i'll have a look at the js for it

Comment: I have put it at the end (after the event has been loaded) of the sf.js file but it still does not seem to do anything